# Set Cell Value Using PHP Variable In FPDF

Tags: php, pdf

I'm trying to use a php variable in my fpdf document, however I can't seem to get it to work. Of course I must be missing something. I thought it would work by creating a new variable for fpdf with `$newVariable="'"$oldVariable"'"` but of course this hasn't worked. I'm using a date as an example if someone could help me here I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

```
$date = date("y-m-d");
$newDate = date("d-m-y", strtotime($date));

$pdfDate = "'".$newDate."'";

require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetXY(10,10); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial',$pdfDate,12);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'',0,0);

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, you should try to read your own code:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial',$pdfDate,12);
```

...you pass the date value to the SetFont() method which makes absolutely no sense... then you call

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'',0,0);
```

with an empty string. What do you expect from such logic?

For sure this is not a final answer but it should let you fix your problem by your own.